# Caching Tomcat HttpClient testing

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, caching

I'm using HttpClient for testing and when I have been restarting/redeploying to Tomcat I have been getting some sort of client side caching... For example I tried deleting my authentication servlet and ran my tester class (which connects using HttpClient) and I get the same response over and over. I'm going crazy trying to figure out what exactly is happening here.

Comment: Which HttpClient class are you talking about?

Comment: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient foo = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: Were you using HttpClient on the client-side or the server-side to call other services? I ran into a similar issue with HttpClient caching some information on the server-side. Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please bear with me as I'm editing this on my mobile device.

In your META-INF/context.xml, add a `PersistentManager` with `saveOnRestart` set to false.

Example:

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false">
       <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore" />
</Manager>
```

---

**PS** If this didn't help you, try this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415520/how-do-i-make-tomcat-stop-caching-my-servlet-responses).

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't even using  context.xml (I'm very new to this).

This is the extent of what I did with no results after restarting the container/redploying.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false">
       <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore" />
</Manager>
</Context>

Comment: No same place as before. I might try deploying it to a new copy of the container.